# 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath File "C:\Users\luigi\Downloads\script_sbs.py", line 20

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, selenium4

```py
import re
import time
from datetime import datetime
from operator import itemgetter

import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.minimize_window()

url = 'https://www.sbostats.com/partite'

tgame = []

driver.get(url)

tab = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/app-root/div/app-matches/section")
tab1 = tab.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

Answer (score 0):

All the methods like `find_element_by_name`, `find_element_by_xpath`, `find_element_by_id` etc. are deprecated now.
You should use `find_element(By.` instead.
So, instead of

```py
tab = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/app-root/div/app-matches/section")
```

it should be now

```py
tab = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/app-root/div/app-matches/section")
```

The same about

```py
tab1 = tab.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

It should be changed to

```py
tab1 = tab.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
```

You will need to import this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Also, you have to improve your locators.
Long absolute XPaths and CSS Selectors like this `/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/app-root/div/app-matches/section` are extremely breakable and not reliable.

Comment: hi, 
it gives me this error: File "c: \ Users \ luigi \ Downloads \ script_sbs.py", line 20, in <module>
     tab = driver.find_element (By, XPATH, "/ html / body / div [2] / div [3] / div / div / div [2] / app-root / div / app-matches / section")
NameError: name 'By' is not defined

I'm sorry but I'm a newbie, I didn't do this code

Comment: Ah, OK. See the updated answer. You will need this import `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Comment: What SyntaxError? please share more details.

Comment: Hi,
adding what you suggested gives me the error described

Comment: Is there a more direct way to contact you? I've been banging my head for months, I'd be grateful

Comment: There is a chat room on my profile page